# Java passing scanner into method

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

So I'm going through a bunch of basic programming ideas to help me get the hang of Java and I created a program that will print PI up to the 10th decimal place (and I can add more if I want).

However, I decided to go an extra step and create an option to keep running the program over and over until the user tells it to stop. I created a method to return either true (run again) or false (exit program). Originally I created a scanner in the method to take user input, and the program runs fine that way, but it tells me I have a resource leak because I didn't close the scanner in the method.

I have just passed the input scanner from main to the method as a parameter, but when I run the program it doesn't accept user input and will print out "Sorry, there was an error" (the else{} option in the if-else statement in my method). Now, I can go back and create a seperate scanner but my OCD doesn't want Eclipse telling me there is a resource leak (I think input.close() closes both scanners, but I am not sure).

Here is my code, I apologize to any Java enthusiasts who become smitten and offended at any bad practices I am unaware of, I am learning.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;

 public class PiDecimalFormat {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#");
         int decPlace = 0;
         boolean runProgram = true;

         System.out.println("This program will print out PI to the decimal place of your choosing.");

         while (runProgram == true) {
             System.out.print("\nEnter the number of decimal places (up to 10) that \nyou would like to print PI to: ");
             decPlace = input.nextInt();

             switch (decPlace) {
                 case 0:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#");
                     break;
                 case 1:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                     break;
                 case 2:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                     break;
                 case 3:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                     break;
                 case 4:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
                     break;
                 case 5:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
                     break;
                 case 6:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
                     break;
                 case 7:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#.#######");
                     break;
                 case 8:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
                     break;
                 case 9:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#.#########");
                     break;
                 case 10:
                     format = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");
                     break;
             }

             System.out.println("\nThe value of PI to " + decPlace + " decimal places is " + format.format(Math.PI) + ".");

             runProgram = AskRunAgain(input);
         }

         input.close();
     }

     static boolean AskRunAgain(Scanner askUser) {
         String userChoice;

         System.out.print("\nWould you like to run the program again? [y/n]: ");
         userChoice = askUser.nextLine();

         if ((userChoice.equals("y")) || (userChoice.equals("Y")) || (userChoice.equals("yes")) || 
            (userChoice.equals("Yes")) || (userChoice.equals("YES"))) { 
             return true;
         }
         else if ((userChoice.equals("n")) || (userChoice.equals("N")) || (userChoice.equals("no")) || 
            (userChoice.equals("No")) || (userChoice.equals("NO"))) {
             System.out.println("\nExitting the program. have a good day!");
             return false;
         }
         else {
             System.out.println("Sorry, there was an error.");
             return false;
         }
     }
 }
```

If anyone could tell me why it is doing this, I would appreciate it. I'm new to Java (decent with C/C++/C# and Python). I didn't see other questions about this specific problem, and it's not a big deal if I just create another scanner in the method.

Comment: If you print out what userChoice was in the `println` inside of the `AskRunAgain()` method, what does it print out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that you're doing this call:

```
decPlace = input.nextInt();
```

The return character isn't consumed, so it is still on the buffer as far as the `Scanner` is concerned.

This means, for an input of `2\n`, it will read the 2 as the next integer, but read an empty string for the call to `nextLine()`.

To get past this, finish consuming the line by using `input.nextLine()` after you read the next integer.

```
decPlace = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change and it will work.

```
askUser.nextLine();
```

**TO**

askUser.next();

```
static boolean AskRunAgain(Scanner askUser) {
        String userChoice;

        System.out.print("\nWould you like to run the program again? [y/n]: ");
        userChoice = askUser.next();
```